# Where is full documentation for google's repo tool?

Tags: android, repo

All I can find is this:
https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html 
But they seem to have focused on simplicity and accessibility, rather than deep, complete documentation of the calibre of man and vim.

For example, 
I'd like to see every possible option to the repo sync command, and what it does, and including whether or not it accepts partial unambiguous flag names if you (intentionally or accidentally) don't type the whole --thin .  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code to repo can be found here: https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo.

I found it by googling `google repo source`

**Updated to answer your question better:**

Try

```
repo help
```

To get more information on a command and see what arguments it takes:

```
repo help sync
```

I also found documentation here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/repo.1.html

You can find documentation on many Linux commands by typing

```
<command> help
```

or

```
man <command>
```

Where `<command>` is the actual command that you need more information on.

Comment: That's a neat idea - looking in the code instead of at documentation.  But can you clarify if there are any files among the source code files that are more like documentation, rather than code?  Sometimes a reference manual is more useful and faster to use than studying the entire code base for something.  Thanks.

Comment: I see. How about trying "repo help", this will give you a list of command. To get more information about each command, such as "abandon", you would type "repo help abandon". Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: THanks, I will accept this answer.  The link didn't help as it just points to the "light" documentation I already referred to.  "repo help sync" helped.  Oddly enough I had tried it once, but it gave me back almost nothing because I hadn't initialized a repo first.  Thanks for pushing me to try that again, it still isn't thorough about --no-tags, but it's the best possible answer, I think.

Comment: this is not so obvious as you think. ubuntu's man page does not cover lots of key for `repo sync`. and `repo help sync` only works if issued inside directory with repo repository. otherwise it says `error: 'sync' is not a bootstrap command.`.